# Generar reporte al enviar formulario PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Necesito ayuda con respecto al envió de un formulario y que al mismo tiempo me genere el reporte de los datos enviados por el mismo, es decir que al presionar el botón guardar se inserten los datos (parte que ya tengo hecha) pero que ademas me dirija hacia el reporte generado, mi código es el siguiente:

**Aquí inicio el envío del formulario**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-submit', function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();
      var btn_button = $(this);
      if($("#formcita").valid() == true){
        var data = $("#formcita").serialize();
        btn_button.html(' <i class="fa fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Procesando...');
        btn_button.attr("disabled",true);
        $.post('save_cita.php', data, function(data,status){
          console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
          if( data == "1"){
            //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            $(".alert-danger").hide();
            $(".alert-success").fadeIn(800);
            btn_button.html('<i class="fa fa fa-check-circle"></i> Hecho');
            setTimeout(function(){  location.reload(); }, 2000);
          }
          else{
            //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            $(".alert-success").hide();
            $(".alert-danger").fadeIn(800);
            btn_button.html('Guardar').attr("disabled",false);
          }
        });
      }
    });

});
```

**luego lo recibo en este archivo para el proceso inserción **

```
if($form_name == 'add_cita'){
$fcita = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['fcita']);
$hcita = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['hcita']);
$coment = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['coment']);
$numdon = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['numdon']);
$numafi = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['numafi']);


$query = "INSERT INTO citas (fechaCita,horaCita,comentario,dui_donantes,afi_pacientes)
          values('$fcita','$hcita','$coment','$numdon','$numafi')"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli-> connect_error);
if($result)
    echo "1";
else
    echo "0";
}
```

si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia o idea de que podría agregar a mi código para hacer lo dicho anteriormente, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no tienes problema en que al imprimir se quede la pre-visualizacion del PDF y  tu usuario tenga que dar para atras o escribir la pagina para redireccionarse creo que FPDF es buena opcion,

tendrias que hacer algo asi..

```
require('fpdf.php');
    if($form_name == 'add_cita'){
$fcita = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['fcita']);
$hcita = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['hcita']);
$coment = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['coment']);
$numdon = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['numdon']);
$numafi = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['numafi']);


$query = "INSERT INTO citas (fechaCita,horaCita,comentario,dui_donantes,afi_pacientes)
          values('$fcita','$hcita','$coment','$numdon','$numafi')"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli-> connect_error);
if($result)
    $pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 5, utf8_decode('FCITA =' . $fcita), 0, 'C');
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 5, utf8_decode('HCITA =' . $hcita), 0, 'C');
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();
else
    echo "0";
}
```

Tambien te recomiendo echarle un ojo a la JSPDF para generar PDF sin la previsualizacion del PDF. https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: Gracias por el dato, porque al final termine haciendo el reporte con jsPDF y pues creo que quedo mucho mejor que con fpdf

Answer (score 0):

si con sacar reporte te refieres a mostrar un modal o un mensaje mostrando los datos que acabo de guardar en base de datos ?

Si es así, lo podrías conseguir con Jquery llamando los valores de los campos por el id, ejemplo...
Si tienes en el formulario un input con id="nombre"

```
if( data == "1"){

alert("Se acaba de guardar el siguiente dato en la base de datos"+("#nombre").val());
        $(".alert-danger").hide();
        $(".alert-success").fadeIn(800);
        btn_button.html('<i class="fa fa fa-check-circle"></i> Hecho');
        setTimeout(function(){  location.reload(); }, 2000);
      }
```

Comment: pues con reporte me refería la biblioteca FPDF ya que luego deseo imprimir los datos del registro que envié por el formulario